# Exercise books in Banach algebra

Tags: reference-request, banach-algebras

I'm studying  Banach algebra and I was wondering if there are some exercise books (that is, books with ***solved*** problems and exercises) 
The books I'm searching for should be:

- full of *hard*, *non-obvious*, *non-common*, and *thought-provoking* problems;
- rich of *complete*, *step by step*, *rigorous*, and *enlightening* solutions;

Comment: That sounds like it would be an amazingly valuable book. // Can you supply the name of such books for any field of math?  Because I would love to read them; I would love even more being able to write one.

Comment: Which books are you mean?

Comment: I doubt such books exist. On the other hand, and I speak as a self-taught (self-teaching better put) person, with little formal training in math, there is no substitute for sitting down and sweating over the exercises. There are always sites like this one where you can get help. I did every exercise in Mac Lane's CWM, and it took me two years but it was well worth it because now I am into homology/cohomology, which is mostly applications of category theory.